# Should I ask my research advisor for extra hourly work as a gap-year research assistant (not a student)?

Tags: research-process, salary, research-assistantship

I'm currently working as a post-bac researcher with my undergraduate advisor in the US, but lost my funding last summer. So, I have been doing the research as voluntary work and work odd jobs that are not contributing to my career just to pay the bills. I'm in a tight financial situation where earning some extra money would be good.

Since I am not a graduate student, would it be reasonable to ask my advisor if I can be paid for some side research and TA-related work (e.g. grading papers for a class)? Does this seem like atypical request to a professor?

Comment: What´s a "post-bac"?

Comment: It's seldom-used in the US to mean a research assistant that has a Bachelor's but isn't in graduate school yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with asking.  However, I suspect it's unlikely you'll get it.  Such work is often restricted to enrolled students only.

Comment: I think this depends on the country. In Germany there are different kinds of contracts. One kind is for students only ("Hiwis") and they have low pay, the other contracts are normal, time-limited work contracts ("Angestellter") that everyone can get if the have the necessary skills/education.

Comment: @JayFromA: Yes.  OP specified the US, and this answer is based on my experience in the US.

Comment: I actually managed to get hourly TA-related tasks in my department to operate equipment for a lab class, but that has only for Fall. I'll definitely ask but feel pessimistic about getting work like you said.